# Background image is not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer, browser

Background image is not showing in IE. Whereas its showing well in Chrome.

Here is the CSS:

```
.banner1 {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner-1.jpg)!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner2 {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner-2.jpg);
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner3 {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner-3.jpg)!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner4 {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner-4.jpg)!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}
```

html:

```
     <div class="right_bx">


<span class="banner1"></span>

      </div>
 <div class="right_bx">
          <span class="banner2"> </span>
      </div>
 <div class="right_bx">
          <span class="banner3"></span>
      </div>
 <div class="right_bx">
          <span class="banner4"></span>
      </div>
```

When I refresh the page I see banner 1 image appearing. The image in fisrt div is apperaing in IE..For example if I give banner 2 in first div I am able to see banner 2 image. But subsequent div images are not showing up in IE

Comment: What's version of IE do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work but try this

```
.banner1 {
  background-image: "assets/images/banner-1.jpg"!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner2 {
  background-image: "assets/images/banner-2.jpg";
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner3 {
  background-image: "assets/images/banner-3.jpg"!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner4 {
  background-image: "assets/images/banner-4.jpg"!important;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried Paul but no luck. Here my problem is whichever I placed in the first div is working fine. But the subsequent divs are not working.

Comment: Sorry was really the only thing i could think of some browsers are funny with file paths. I cant see a problem with the code are you using the latest version of internet explorer ? maybe even try run it on Microsoft edge?

Comment: Edge is working fine. I am using IE11. Anyways thanks Paul

Comment: No problem, sorry i couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

use `background: url("...");` or 
  `background-image: url("...");` also don't use `/`  at the beginning of the file path.

Change `/assets/images/banner-1.jpg` to this: `assets/images/banner-1.jpg` etc.

```
.banner1 {
  background: url("assets/images/banner-1.jpg");
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner2 {
  background: url("assets/images/banner-2.jpg");
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner3 {
  background: url("assets/images/banner-3.jpg");
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}

.banner4 {
  background: url("assets/images/banner-4.jpg");
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check the related elements (whether the image load success or not, and the CSS style). I suppose perhaps the issue is related the div container is empty, so the image not display. you could try to fill content to the div, or refer to the following code to set the fix height property:

```
.right_bx{
    height: 200px;
}
```